# Sending & Receiving "Nudges" via tcp?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

I'm tyring to add a feature to my app that sends a nudge to all users of my program (family members inside the house), and when they receive the nudge the window of my app on their computer shakes for a second...

Can somebody please suggest how i'd have to go about this? I've never worked with tcp/ip before.. Is this what I should use, or is there something better?

I have tried to come up with my own solution however none of the samples ever work. So I thought maybe the people on SO might know of other ways?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you set up in a client/server fashion, where all of your users have a connection to a centralized server of some sort? Or are you operating in a peer to peer fashion? Are all of the users you'd want to "nudge" running on the same subnet, or on different ones? Do you know the IP or MAC addresses of the people you'd want to nudge?

Comment: well, for some silly reason my son wanted to go with a different internet service provider so we're on different networks. and i don't know the ip's of any of them, but i do know that our ip addresses are dynamic - so they're always changing, which i think would make things harder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider UDP for this. Since you can broadcast/multicast via UDP it may be more suitable for this sort of application. There are downsides - UDP transmission is not *reliable* or *guaranteed* in the same way as TCP.

Answer (score 5):

If this is just an "in-house" (pardon the pun) application, and you're all on the same network, you might consider sending a UDP broadcast packet. Each instance of your application could listen for a packet on a particular port, and when the correct one is received do the window shake thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a good [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) Library.  Maybe [Jabber-Net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/)?

You'll also have the added bonus of being able to connect to Google Chat and now Facebook chat later.

You haven't specified if presence in your case requires a server or not.  If it is client/server oriented, using XMPP gives you the server side for "free" as a bonus.

Comment: hmmm this looks interesting. thanks for the link... the reason i didn't specify whether or not it was client/server oriented was because i don't know much about this stuff and didn't want to restrict the answers to just one thing... if that makes any sense? :)

Comment: sure. "Presence" requires first locating potential peers.  There are lots of ways to do this but a client/server approach is by far the most popular.

Comment: I just tried jabber-net. It doesn't work with Windows 7 Home Premium. The installer says "Operating System must be newer than Windows 2000"... How wrong it is lol